# Routing cables under the house with raised perimeter foundation

Tags: walls, foundation, cabling

Rather a simple question, I want to route some cables under the house with a raised perimeter foundation.

The question is, how should I pass the cables I'm routing from under the house into the wall up above?

This is the closest resemblance to my foundation (from my untrained eye)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Drill up into the wall

### Drill on an angle

You could try and dill up from underneath at just the right angle. Though this might be difficult, since you may not have much room to work and getting the proper angle could be impossible.

[image: Drill at an angle]

## Use a flexible bit

In some situations, there might be enough room available to get a flexible bit into position from below. Though again, space may be limited making it difficult.

[image: Drill from the bottom with flexible bit]

## Drill down

The more appropriate way to accomplish this task, is to drill from the top down. Start by cutting an access hole in the wall. About the size of an electrical box will do. This might be convenient, if you're installing a receptacle or something in the area. If you're not installing a device, cut the hole large enough to give yourself plenty of room to work. Patching a large hole in drywall is just as easy as patching a small one (sometimes easier).

Once you have the hole, use a flexible drill bit to drill down through the bottom plate. Use and alignment tool, to make sure the bit is in the proper position.

[image: Drill from the top with flexible bit]

[image: Placement tool]
<sup>*Flexible drill bit placement tool*</sup>
[image: Flexible bit]
<sup>*Flexible drill bit*</sup>
[image: Man drilling down through wall]
<sup>*Man using a flexible drill bit*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Careful measuring and (for exterior walls) a right angle drill, generally does the trick.
Note that from below you generally can't see where the walls are, as you're looking at floorboards.

Answer (score 1):

With something like this

http://www.screwfix.com/p/armeg-sds-plus-channelling-chisel-30mm/16724

If you are going to remove the skirting boards, a normal SDS chisel or drill bit is usually enough.